# Upgrade Xcode 10 when open old project which created by xcode 9.2 when open storyboard was stucked

Tags: swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I moved my project to new mac and install lastest version xcode 10, everything would be fine but when click the storyboard, it was stucked.
My pc was 16G memory and 512 SSD hard disk, Is there any setting I was missed?

Comment: Can you build your project?

Comment: @kubrickG yes i can build my project

Comment: You may have invalid content in your storyboard, try opening it as plain text and see if you could found anything abnormal.

Comment: @kubrickG I can use my old mac even slow but not stuck....